# Android app to stream music from phone to PC over Bluetooth or USB

Tags: android, music, streaming

I'm looking for an Android app which will stream music (MP3 files) from my phone to my PC over Bluetooth or USB.

The app can have a client software on PC (Windows or Ubuntu).